# Changing text on buttons etc on mobile app which is already in production

Tags: iphone, android, updates

Let's say we have a mobile app (iPhone, Android) already deployed and being used by people.

Is it possible to change text on buttons, title bars, or even shape or colour of these things without a major update? What I mean is, do we have to deploy an update to the whole app (for example, new version) in order to change one single text on the button? Or maybe these things (settings) can be stored in some kind of database or XML?

Help me out on this one please. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

> > Is it possible to change text on buttons, title bars, or even shape or colour of these things without a major update?

No. You have to deploy a new version, even if you want to change a single thing like that.

It's possible to do changes to an existing app without deploying a new version, but in your case it's not possible. This is how it works:

- You create a mechanism to check for *new updates*.
- New updates can be new data, new settings, etc.
- You make your app download and use that new data.

The problem here is that you have to have already deployed an app that do the steps above. Since your app currently does not have that implemented, there's no way to do any changes to it but updating it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your app.  I implemented the consumption of a JSON string recently to display a Message of the Day periodically.  It also keeps a "low watermark" that I compare against the user's running version.  If their version is too old I present them with 2 options: upgrade or quit.

You could as easily make your text work in the same way.  Just be sure to keep a local cache in case they don't have network access.  Will require some healthy refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

you are able to store the text of buttons in values/Strings.xml and set them to the controls by `text="@String/text_for_buttonxy"` . This is grat for multiple languages, because you are able to put the Strings.xml in a country-code ending value folder like values-de values-en or values-fr in order to get the right String based on the phonesettungs.
Vor colors you are able to to the same thing with the colors.xml.
But you won't be able to change this xml file by synchronisation with a server, this will be a litte bit more complicated, please explain how to you want to change the settings.